# Effect of Alter Table Import TableSpace on InnoDB Buffer Pool in MySql?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to understand the impact of Import TableSpace for the alter command on innodb's buffer pool.

Since the table space is being imported and rows are being inserted, would all pages be bought into the Buffer Pool during the import? or does the Import TableSpace actually skip the buffer pool completely ?

The only information i could find is in the storage/innobase/row/row0import.cc in a comment under Phase III - Flush changes to disk which says

> Ensure that all pages dirtied during the IMPORT make it to disk.   The
>   only dirty pages generated should be from the pessimistic purge   of
>   delete marked records that couldn't be purged in Phase I

The Mysql Version is 5.7

Comment: I think the following is correct (but don't have enough confidence to make it an Answer):  `IMPORT TABLESPACE` is a _file_ manipulation operation.  A few changes will be made to `ibdata1` (or 8.0's Data Dictionary), but no _records_ will be shoveled around.  (I don't know how to reconcile the quote you presented.)  Have you timed a _large_ `IMPORT`?  I expect it to be too fast to involve much I/O.

Comment: It's a large import. But we run import table space on live server's. I suspect it somehow invalidates existing buffer pool by bringing in the pages of the import tablespace causing query performance on other tables to be bad. Thats why i am wondering how it might affect the buffer pool. I do know that import tablespace ends up writing table space ids to every page, but i am not sure if it ends up bring the pages to buffer pool. Also the version is 5.7

Comment: The task will also be doing a lot of I/O.  How big is the table?  How long does the import take?  Aha -- the tablespace ids -- Yeah, that might mess up the buffer pool temporarily.  How often do you do such an import??